# Appending the results of a load() into a table with JQuery and formatting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append data from a JQuery load() into a table.While i am able to append the data into the table successfully, the appended results are not formatted in line with the rest of the table.

**Current Format of table(after appending)**

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                    Data                           |
-----------------------------------------------------
|    Data                |            Data          |
-----------------------------------------------------
|    Data                |            Data          |
-----------------------------------------------------
|Append data|Append data |
--------------------------
|Append data|Append data |
--------------------------
|Append data|Append data |
--------------------------
|Append data|Append data |
--------------------------
```

**Desired Format**

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                    Data                           |
-----------------------------------------------------
|    Data                |            Data          |
-----------------------------------------------------
|    Data                |            Data          |
-----------------------------------------------------
|      Append Data       |        Append Data       |
 -----------------------------------------------------
|      Append Data       |        Append Data       |
-----------------------------------------------------
|      Append Data       |        Append Data       |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

**Extract of code:**

```
    <table id="edititemtable" border='1'>

<tr>
    <td colspan='2'>Item Info</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Select Category: </td>
    <td>
        <select id='changeitemcat' name='changeitemcat'></select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Select SubCategory: </td>
    <td>
        <select id='changeitemsubcat' name='changeitemsubcat'></select>
    </td>
</tr>

<div id="details" name="details">
</div>

</table>
```

**Extract of JQuery Used**

```
$("#edititemtable").append($("#details").load('changeitem.php?cat='+cat+'&subcat='+subcat+'&item='+item));
```

Extract of .load() file

```
while($extractdetails=$getitem->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
//Data is saved into the associated variables


echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>";
        echo"Item Name";
    echo"</td>";
    echo"<td>";
        echo"<input type='text' id='changeitemname' name='changeitemname' value=$itemname size='30' maxlength='50' />";
    echo"</td>";
echo"</tr>";    

echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>";
        echo"Item Price";
    echo"</td>";
    echo"<td>";
        echo"<input type='text' id='changeitemprice' name='changeitemprice' value=$itemprice size='7' maxlength='7' />";
    echo"</td>";
echo"</tr>";

echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>";
        echo"Item Info";
    echo"</td>";
    echo"<td>";
        echo"<textarea class='textarea' id='changeiteminfo' name='changeiteminfo' col='10' rows='10' maxlength='300' >$iteminfo</textarea>";
    echo"</td>";
echo"</tr>";


echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>";
        echo'<form id="changeitem" name="changeitem" method="POST" action="">';
            echo"<input type='hidden' id='changeitemid' name='changeitemid' value='$itemid' />";
            echo"<input type='submit' id='changeitemsubmit' name='changeitemsubmit' value='Save Changes' />";
        echo"</form>";
    echo"</td>";
echo"</tr>";
```

}

**QUESTION**

How do i get the desired format?

Why is the appended data being forced into one  of the ?

**SOLUTION:**

```
<table id="edititemtable" border='1'>

<tr>
    <td colspan='2'>Item Info</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Select Category: </td>
    <td>
        <select id='changeitemcat' name='changeitemcat'></select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Select SubCategory: </td>
    <td>
        <select id='changeitemsubcat' name='changeitemsubcat'></select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="details" name="details">
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

P.s I'm currently using HTML 5 and PHP

Comment: the new table rows are being loaded into a div inside the existing table, that wont work as you'd like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**in html**

```
<table id="edititemtable" border='1'>

<tr>
    <td colspan='2'>Item Info</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Select Category: </td>
    <td>
        <select id='changeitemcat' name='changeitemcat'></select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Select SubCategory: </td>
    <td>
        <select id='changeitemsubcat' name='changeitemsubcat'></select>
    </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
<table id="details" name="details" >
</table>
        </td> 
        </tr>
</table>
```

**in js**

```
  $("#edititemtable").append($("#details").load('changeitem.php?cat='+cat+'&subcat='+subcat+'&item='+item));
```

Comment: I've already tried that, i am able to load the appended data successfully but it is squeezed into one <td> (i.e the current format i am getting)

Comment: I got the solution(I've updated my question with it) Ill accept your answer as it was the closest to the solution (and helped me out)

Comment: i edited my code see i made a td in this apply colspan so it will fit your data

Answer (score 1):

Putting a `<div>` inside a `<table>` isn't valid (if it's not inside a `<tr>` and `<td>`), so you're going to see "incorrect" (as far as you're concerned) results if you try to do that. The simplest solution would be to change it from a `<div>` to a `<tbody>` element, which is perfectly valid to be inside a `<table>` element and contain table rows:

```
<table id="edititemtable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Item Info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Select Category:</td>
        <td>
            <select id="changeitemcat" name="changeitemcat"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Select SubCategory:</td>
        <td>
            <select id="changeitemsubcat" name="changeitemsubcat"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="details"></tbody>
</table>
```

There's also no need to call `.append()` since that element is already at the end of your table. Just do:

```
$('#details').load('changeitem.php?cat='+cat+'&subcat='+subcat+'&item='+item);
```